# WebSphere MQ: Inhibit Put on Queue Mager level for workload balancing purposes

Tags: ibm-mq

We have 3 Queue Managers in a cluster to provide workload balancing. QM1 and QM2 are full repositories, QM3 serves for client application connections.

To put QM1 or QM2 out of the loop for the workload balancing algorithm, I need to shut down the queue managers. But I'd like to put them in a state that is similar to the InhibitPut state of the queue, just that it would need to be at the queue manager level. This would enable the consumers to finish consuming messages first. I could put the InhibitPut on each queue, but there's hundreds.

Any idea of how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by turning off the cluster channels then the queue manager will not be reachable. I would recommend that you only do this to one of the full repositories at a time however.